# How to convert ArrayList to SQL ArrayList

Tags: java, list, jdbc, arraylist

I need your help in fixing the error of converting an arraylist to a SQL arraylist. In my code, I am storing the selected values from the user in the `selectedRequests` list and then I am doing a for loop for retrieving and printing the components of the list. However, I faced few difficulties while assigning the retrieved values to an `arraylist`, so I decided to use `list` and then I passed the list to the SQL arraylist.

The error which I am getting is:

> java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:
>   [2015000015]java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal
>   representation: [2015000015]
>                   at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeNUMBER.cArrayToNUMBERArray(OracleTypeNUMBER.java:452)
>                   at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeNUMBER.toNUMBERArray(OracleTypeNUMBER.java:339)

And it is referring to the below line and exactly to the tranNoArrList:

```
ArrayDescriptor arrdescrTranNo = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("HRD.LEV_ENCSEQ", con);
                ARRAY tranNoArrTopass = new ARRAY(arrdescrTranNo, con, tranNoArrList);
```

The code which is in the method is:

```
String[] tranNoArr = new String[3];
List<String> tranNoArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] apprStatusArr = new String[3];
List<String> apprStatusList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] rejectionReasonArr = new String[3];
List<String>  rejectionReasonArrList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (PendingRequests p : selectedRequests) {
             System.out.println(p.getRequestNo());
             System.out.println(p.getApprovalStatus());
             System.out.println(p.getRejectionReason());

             tranNoArrList.add(p.getRequestNo());
             apprStatusList.add(p.getApprovalStatus());
             rejectionReasonArrList.add(p.getRejectionReason());
                    }

            // tranno
ArrayDescriptor arrdescrTranNo = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("HRD.LEV_ENCSEQ", con);
                ARRAY tranNoArrTopass = new ARRAY(arrdescrTranNo, con, tranNoArrList);

            // ApprovalStatus
ArrayDescriptor arrdescrApprStatus = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("HRD.LEV_ACTIONFLG", con);

 ARRAY apprStatusArrTopass = new ARRAY(arrdescrApprStatus, con, apprStatusList);
                    //RejectionReason
    ArrayDescriptor arrdescrRejectionReason =
                        ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("HRD.LEV_REJREASONTYP", con);
    ARRAY rejectionReasonArrTopass = new ARRAY(arrdescrRejectionReason, con, rejectionReasonArrList);
```

SO can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle `ARRAY` constructor takes an array as its third argument, not a `List`.

Replace

```
    ARRAY tranNoArrTopass = new ARRAY(arrdescrTranNo, con, tranNoArrList);
```

with

```
    ARRAY tranNoArrTopass = new ARRAY(arrdescrTranNo, con, tranNoArrList.toArray());
```

and similarly for the other arrays.

Incidentally, as `tranNoArrList` appears to contain numbers, consider defining `tranNoArrList` as `List<Integer>` or perhaps `List<BigDecimal>`, rather than `List<String>`.  Otherwise, if a non-numeric value such as `"N/A"` ends up in your list of transaction numbers, you will encounter an error when Oracle tries and fails to convert this to a number.  Of course, this may have knock-on changes elsewhere in your code: for example, you may have to change the type of `PendingRequest.getRequestNo()` to be numeric.

Comment: Instead of the List, can I use directly the array and add the values to the array and then to pass it to the Oracle constructor?

Comment: @user2438318: yes, you can do that.